# How can I make a non-assisted dependency assisted?

Tags: java, guice, assisted-inject

Suppose I have a third party class as follows:

```
public class MyObject {
    @Inject
    public MyObject(Foo foo, Bar bar) { ... }
}
```

Now suppose that I have a factory interface like so:

```
public interface MyObjectFactory {
    public MyObject build(Bar bar);
}
```

The idea is that I wish to have a `MyObjectFactory` that builds a `MyObject` for a fixed `Foo` - that is, essentially adding in the [`@Assisted`](http://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/latest/javadoc/com/google/inject/assistedinject/Assisted.html) annotation on the `Bar` constructor parameter from the outside.  Of course, manually implementing `MyObjectFactory` is always possible:

```
public class MyObjectFactoryImpl implements MyObjectFactory {
    @Inject private Provider<Foo> foo;

    @Override
    public MyObject build(Bar bar) { return new MyObject(foo.get(), bar); }
}
```

But let's say that there are conditions that require me to have Guice build `MyObject` instances - for example, method interceptors.  This seems like a job for "injecting the injector":

```
public class MyObjectFactoryImpl implements MyObjectFactory {
    @Inject private Injector injector;

    @Override
    public MyObject build(Bar bar) {
        Injector child = injector.createChildInjector(new AbstractModule() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(Bar.class).toInstance(bar);
                // Set up method interceptors for MyObject here...
            }
        });
        return child.getInstance(MyObject.class);
    }
}
```

This sounds evil and boiler-plate-y, so I'm wondering if there are any alternate implementations and/or a way to have Guice generate the factory impl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is rare that you want to be passing instances of `MyObject` around in your class for exactly the reasons you describe. You have no control over them, so you can't add `@Assisted` annotations, you can't add method interceptors, etc. etc. Plus, what happens when you want to swap out the third party library for a different implementation?

Therefore, you should be wrapping `MyObject` into another object.

```
// **Please** choose better names than this in your real code.
public class MyWrapperBackedByMyObject implements MyWrapperInterface {
    private final MyObject delegate;

    @Inject
    MyWrapperObject(Foo foo, @Assisted Bar bar) {
        delegate = new MyObject(foo, bar);
    }

    @NotOnWeekends  // Example of how you might do method interception
    public void orderPizza() {
       delegate.orderPizza();
    }
}
```

Then, remove all references to `MyObject` throughout your code, using the naming convention I describe above, there should only be references to `MyWrapperInterface`.

Answer (score -1):

actually it is. Have a look [Assisted Inject](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/AssistedInject)

Include

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
            <version>${guice.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Update injection with assisted

```
public class MyInjectedObject extends MyObject implements MyIntf {
@Inject
public MyObject(Foo foo, @Assisted Bar bar) { super(foo,bar); }
}
```

You have to add one more interface:

```
public interface MyIntf {}
```

In your module bind generic factory to your interface

```
    install(new FactoryModuleBuilder()
            .implement(MyIntf.class, MyInjectedObject.class)
            .build(MyObjectFactory.class)
);
```

Now you can inject `MyObjectFactory` anywhere you want.

```
MyObject obj = myObjectFactory.build(bar);
```

Comment: Again, since `MyObject` is third-party, I cannot modify `MyObject`; otherwise I'd be able to just use plain old assisted injection.

Comment: Wrap it around into another object.